# IP camera video stream texture not being provided to Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ip-camera, render-to-texture

My goal is to create a Unity AR application (which will later be exported to Android) where the user can see what an IP camera is streaming.

For that, I'm using a mesh renderer (a quad in this case) to display the image and then added an AR camera in the Unity world pointing at it.
I got most of the following code from around the Internet and I was told that I would need to use a C# script reference called **LoadRawTextureData()** in order to convert the stream bytes into texture.

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class IPCamConfig : MonoBehaviour
{

    [HideInInspector]
    public Byte[] JpegData;
    [HideInInspector]
    public string resolution = "320x240";

    private Texture2D camTexture;
    public Stream stream;
    private WebResponse resp;
    public MeshRenderer frame;

private void Start()
    {
        GetVideo();
        FindLength(stream);
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        StopStream();
    }

    public void GetVideo()
    {
        // create HTTP request
        resolution = "320x240";
        string url = "http://192.168.1.104/videostream.asf?usr=admin&pwd=" + resolution + "&resolution=320*240";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        // get response
        resp = req.GetResponse();


        camTexture = new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);

        camTexture.LoadRawTextureData(JpegData);
        camTexture.Apply();
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = camTexture;

        // get response stream
        stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        frame.material.color = Color.white;
        StartCoroutine(GetFrame());
    }

    public IEnumerator GetFrame()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int bytesToRead = FindLength(stream);
            if (bytesToRead == -1)
            {
                //                print("End of stream");
                yield break;
            }

            int leftToRead = bytesToRead;

            while (leftToRead > 0)
            {
                //                print (leftToRead);
                leftToRead -= stream.Read(JpegData, bytesToRead - leftToRead, leftToRead);
                yield return null;
            }

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(JpegData, 0, bytesToRead, false, true);

            camTexture.LoadImage(ms.GetBuffer());
            frame.material.mainTexture = camTexture;
            frame.material.color = Color.white;

            stream.ReadByte(); // CR after bytes
            stream.ReadByte(); // LF after bytes
        }
    }

    int FindLength(Stream stream)
    {
        int b;
        string line = "";
        int result = -1;
        bool atEOL = false;

        while ((b = stream.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            if (b == 10) continue; // ignore LF char
            if (b == 13)
            { // CR
                if (atEOL)
                {  // two blank lines means end of header
                    stream.ReadByte(); // eat last LF
                    return result;
                }
                if (line.StartsWith("Content-Length:"))
                {
                    result = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring("Content-Length:".Length).Trim());
                }
                else
                {
                    line = "";
                }
                atEOL = true;
            }
            else
            {
                atEOL = false;
                line += (char)b;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    public void StopStream()
    {
        stream.Close();
        resp.Close();
    }
}
```

I've implemented **LoadRawTextureData()** inside the GetVideo() function because that's where it will verify the IP camera URL and supposedly render the texture from its footage.

Instead, when I run the application in Unity, I'm constantly getting the following error:

```
UnityEngine.Texture2D:LoadRawTextureData(Byte[])
IPCamConfig:GetVideo() (at Assets/Scripts/IPCamConfig.cs:48)
IPCamConfig:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/IPCamConfig.cs:25)
```

Is there something else I'm missing? Or do I have to use another script reference/API for byte conversion? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You only posted part of the stack trace, i.e. 'where' it crashed. But not the actual error information. What kind of exception is thrown and did it contain an error message?

Comment: @nilsK That is all what appeared in the console. Though I wrote debug messages between lines 45 and 54. It prompts the error right before the first debug message (right on the texture format line) and then it's printed again after the LoadRawTextureData(JpegData) line. I can't find what exception is thrown at the moment.

Comment: Ok it seems the clipboard didn't contain the error description. It says this: "No texture data provided to LoadRawTextureData"
My apologies.

Comment: I just realzied, that your `JpegData` is never initialized. Shouldn't this happen, after you got a response from your stream, i.e. take the responses bytes and put them into `LoadRawTextureData`? Btw.: this seems odd `&pwd=" + resolution + "&resolution=320*240"` typo? you mixed resolution and pwd, but then, you set credentials.

Comment: @nilsK by that you mean that the function where it's initiaziled (which is GetFrame) should be written before LoadRawTextureData()?
As for the resolution and credentials thing, that's exactly how it was in the code I've found in Unity answers, and the author said it worked like a charm for them.